# Не работают шейдеры в OpenGL

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, opengl

если кратко, то созданые шейдеры никак не влияют на результат, попросту не работают.
Окно WinApi, openGl загружает GLAD, контекс создаю сам, версия 3.3, ошибок при создании контекста нет, все отлично рисуеться, но шейдеры ничего не делают.

Изображение черное, при попытке поиграть со значениями в вершинном шейдере изображение остаеться статично, если убрать весь полезный код из шейдера, результат тот же.

При загрузкt версии 4.6 изображение белое.

Где можно искать ошибку?

Цикл рисования.

```
const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"out vec4 vertexColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y+1, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"   vertexColor = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";

const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"in vec4 vertexColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vertexColor;\n"
"}\n\0";

void update(engine::window::Window* _pWnd) {

    unsigned int shaderProgram = 0;

    unsigned int VBO = 1, VAO = 1, EBO = 1;

    engine::events::Event ev;
    _pWnd->PollEvent(ev);
    if (ev.IsPressed(VK_ESCAPE)) _pWnd->~Window();
    while (1) {
        int a = ev.GetLastEvent();
        if (a == 0) break;

        if (a == WM_CREATE) {

            glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

            int  success;

            unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
            glCompileShader(vertexShader);

            glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

            if (!success) exit(101);

            unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
            glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

            glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

            if (!success) exit(102);

            shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

            glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
            glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
            glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

            glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

            if (!success) exit(103);

            glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
            glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
            glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

            glBindVertexArray(VAO);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  vertices1.size()*4, &vertices1[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,  indices1.size()*4, &indices1[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

            glBindVertexArray(0);



        }}

    long errr = glGetError();

    if (errr) exit(errr);

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices1.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc1);

}
```

Создание контекста.

```
void init_opengl(HDC real_dc)
{
    init_opengl_extensions();

    int pixel_format_attribs[] = {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB,     GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB,     GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB,      GL_TRUE,
        WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB,       WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB,         WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB,         32,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB,         24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB,       8,
        0
    };

    int pixel_format;
    UINT num_formats;
    wglChoosePixelFormatARB(real_dc, pixel_format_attribs, 0, 1, &pixel_format, &num_formats);
    if (!num_formats) {
        exit(4);
    }

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    DescribePixelFormat(real_dc, pixel_format, sizeof(pfd), &pfd);
    if (!SetPixelFormat(real_dc, pixel_format, &pfd)) {
        exit(3);
    }

    int gl33_attribs[] = {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,  WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0,
    };

    HGLRC gl33_context = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(real_dc, 0, gl33_attribs);
    if (!gl33_context) {
        exit(2);
    }

    if (!wglMakeCurrent(real_dc, gl33_context)) {
        exit(1);
    }


    gladLoadGL();
}
```

[image: вывод]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**:
Собрал у себя рабочее **"На коленке"(качество кода - очень так себе но для запуска и взять что-то для себя - ок)** [тестовое решение](https://pastebin.com/z8btqfNF), шейдеры работают нормально. можете прям собрать и попробывать, только 8 строчке - сделайте свой include к GLAD и вот вам [tree.obj](https://pastebin.com/1uJ39NZP).

Предлагаю вам собрать решение для начала, а потом смотреть пункты для чуть более детального понимания.

Давайте пойдем по пунктам, что предлагаю поменять. в формате ваших функций более менее, если что не понятно, то пишите в каком пункте и будет разбирать

1. Создаем фейковое окно и там инициализируем opengl.

```
ATOM registerClass(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(wcex));
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.lpszClassName = "Core";
    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

void init_opengl_extensions() {

    windowClass = MAKEINTATOM(registerClass(hInstance));

    if (windowClass == 0) {
        showMessage("registerClass() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    /// Создаем временное окно ///

    HWND fakeWND = CreateWindow(
        windowClass, "Fake Window",
        style,
        0, 0,                       
        1, 1,                       
        NULL, NULL,                 
        hInstance, NULL);           

    HDC fakeDC = GetDC(fakeWND);    // Device Context

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR fakePFD;
    ZeroMemory(&fakePFD, sizeof(fakePFD));
    fakePFD.nSize = sizeof(fakePFD);
    fakePFD.nVersion = 1;
    fakePFD.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    fakePFD.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    fakePFD.cColorBits = 32;
    fakePFD.cAlphaBits = 8;
    fakePFD.cDepthBits = 24;

    const int fakePFDID = ChoosePixelFormat(fakeDC, &fakePFD);
    if (fakePFDID == 0) {
        showMessage("ChoosePixelFormat() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    if (SetPixelFormat(fakeDC, fakePFDID, &fakePFD) == false) {
        showMessage("SetPixelFormat() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    HGLRC fakeRC = wglCreateContext(fakeDC);    // Rendering Contex

    if (fakeRC == 0) {
        showMessage("wglCreateContext() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    if (wglMakeCurrent(fakeDC, fakeRC) == false) {
        showMessage("wglMakeCurrent() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    /// получаем указатели на функции или вызывает opengl loader

    PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC wglChoosePixelFormatARB = nullptr;
    wglChoosePixelFormatARB = reinterpret_cast<PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC>(wglGetProcAddress("wglChoosePixelFormatARB"));
    if (wglChoosePixelFormatARB == nullptr) {
        showMessage("wglGetProcAddress() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB = nullptr;
    wglCreateContextAttribsARB = reinterpret_cast<PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC>(wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB"));
    if (wglCreateContextAttribsARB == nullptr) {
        showMessage("wglGetProcAddress() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    if (config.windowed == true) {
        adjustSize();
        center();
    }
}
```

2. Вот так создаем окно, поля по типу позиции/размера делать как удобно

```
//// Создаем новое реальное окно ///
                                
    WND = CreateWindow(
        windowClass, "OpenGL Window",   // class name, window name
        style,                          // styles
        config.posX, config.posY,       // posx, posy. If x is set to CW_USEDEFAULT y is ignored
        config.width, config.height,    // width, height
        NULL, NULL,                     // parent window, menu
        hInstance, NULL);               // instance, param

    DC = GetDC(WND);

    const int pixelAttribs[] = {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB, WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_ALPHA_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SAMPLES_ARB, 4,
        0
    };

    int pixelFormatID; UINT numFormats;
    const bool status = wglChoosePixelFormatARB(DC, pixelAttribs, NULL, 1, &pixelFormatID, &numFormats);

    if (status == false || numFormats == 0) {
        showMessage("wglChoosePixelFormatARB() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR PFD;
    DescribePixelFormat(DC, pixelFormatID, sizeof(PFD), &PFD);
    SetPixelFormat(DC, pixelFormatID, &PFD);

    const int major_min = 4, minor_min = 0;
    const int contextAttribs[] = {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, major_min,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, minor_min,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB,
        0
    };

    RC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(DC, 0, contextAttribs);
    if (RC == NULL) {
        showMessage("wglCreateContextAttribsARB() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(fakeRC);
    ReleaseDC(fakeWND, fakeDC);
    DestroyWindow(fakeWND);
    if (!wglMakeCurrent(DC, RC)) {
        showMessage("wglMakeCurrent() failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    /// Запускаем GLAD
    gladLoadGL();

    SetWindowText(WND, reinterpret_cast<LPCSTR>(glGetString(GL_VERSION)));
    ShowWindow(WND, nCmdShow);
```

3. Ваш main будет выглядеть как - то так.

```
int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, wchar_t* pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    engine::window::Window ab;
    ///// Сначала подготавливаем opengl - шаг 1 /////
    init_opengl();

    //// создаем реально окно - шаг 2
    ab.Create(L"Window", engine::math::Vector2i(800, 600));

    //if (FAILED(engine::render::InitContext(ab.GetDescriptor()))) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    UpdateWindow(ab.GetDescriptor());

    Load3DObject(L"models\\cat.obj", &vertices1, &indices1);

    ab.StartLoop(nCmdShow, update);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Я бы на самом деле объеденил `init_opengl() и create()` для удобства, так как шаг **1 и 2** взаимосвязаны.

```
int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, wchar_t* pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    engine::window::Window ab;
    ab.setup() /// шаг 1 + шаг 2

    UpdateWindow(ab.GetDescriptor());

    Load3DObject(L"models\\cat.obj", &vertices1, &indices1);

    ab.StartLoop(nCmdShow, update);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

4. Собрать шейдер в класс и выполнять его работу не на **WM_CREATE** а попозже

Comment: Не помогло, но тут проблема не в этом, программа просто не использует шейдеры, даже если сделать шейдер который ничего не делает, изображение будет.

Comment: @ТимурКрамар вы все равно оставьте пригодится, а давайте тогда посмотрим на само создание контекста OpenGL и самого окна, типо функции init_opengl_extensions

Comment: Ну вот код, больше нигде OpenGL не используеться

Comment: Спасибо за пример, очень занятно, тут шейдер работает как надо, буду сравнивать, большое спасибо

Comment: дело ещё более занятней, скопировал ваш класс шейдера, и все работает

Comment: большое спасибо, на самом деле проблема была в том что после создания шейдера они удалялись, так как update вызываеться постоянно, а обявления шейдера было в нем, я просто добавил модификатор static.

Comment: @ТимурКрамар рад, вам помочь, и советую вам немного архитектуры движку накинуть. Можете мой почитать https://github.com/Enziferum/robot2D :) вдруг вам будет интересно. У меня правда про 2D больше, но суть похожая и с 3D движками

Answer (score 0):

Контекс создаёт `init_opengl(HDC);`

Которая получает в качестве параметра контекст окна.

Дальше идет создание временного вспомагательного окна и создание временного контекста, чтобы получить возможность загрузить необходимые для создания нормального контекста функции.

Использовать WinApi принципиально обязательно.

Создание вспомогательного контекста для загрузки "wglCreateContextAttribsARB".

```
void init_opengl_extensions(void)
{
    WNDCLASSA window_class = {
        .style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC,
        .lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProcA,
        .hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0),
        .lpszClassName = "Dummy_WGL_djuasiodwa",
    };

    if (!RegisterClassA(&window_class));

    HWND dummy_window = CreateWindowExA(
        0,
        window_class.lpszClassName,
        "Dummy OpenGL Window",
        0,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        0,
        0,
        window_class.hInstance,
        0);

    HDC dummy_dc = GetDC(dummy_window);

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { 0 };

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cAlphaBits = 8;

    int pixel_format = ChoosePixelFormat(dummy_dc, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(dummy_dc, pixel_format, &pfd);


    HGLRC dummy_context = wglCreateContext(dummy_dc);

    wglMakeCurrent(dummy_dc, dummy_context);

    wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (wglCreateContextAttribsARB_type*)wglGetProcAddress(
        "wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
    wglChoosePixelFormatARB = (wglChoosePixelFormatARB_type*)wglGetProcAddress(
        "wglChoosePixelFormatARB");

    wglMakeCurrent(dummy_dc, 0);
    wglDeleteContext(dummy_context);
    ReleaseDC(dummy_window, dummy_dc);
    DestroyWindow(dummy_window);
}
```

Ну а главное окно в котором рисуем это класс, вот метод инициализации

```
void engine::window::Window::Create(LPCWSTR _pWindowTitle, engine::math::Vector2i _windowResolution, WNDPROC _pWindowProc) {

    if (_pWindowProc) m_pWndProc = _pWindowProc;

    engine::Alloc(&m_pWndClass);
    engine::Clear(&m_pWndClass);

    m_pWndClass->lpfnWndProc = EngineWindowProc;
    m_pWndClass->lpszClassName = L"ASLFHLASFHQWOQWDS";
    m_pWndClass->hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    m_pWndClass->hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0xccaacc);
    m_pWndClass->hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClass(m_pWndClass);

    engine::AdjustResolution(&_windowResolution);

    m_hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
        NULL,
        L"ASLFHLASFHQWOQWDS",
        _pWindowTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX ,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        _windowResolution.x,
        _windowResolution.y,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        NULL
    );

    SetWindowLongPtrW(m_hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(this));

    engine::Release(m_pWndClass);

}
```

Ну и пожалуй точка входа

```
int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, wchar_t* pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    engine::window::Window ab;
    ab.Create(L"Window", engine::math::Vector2i(800, 600));

    //if (FAILED(engine::render::InitContext(ab.GetDescriptor()))) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    hdc1 = GetDC(ab.GetDescriptor());

    init_opengl(hdc1);

    UpdateWindow(ab.GetDescriptor());

    Load3DObject(L"models\\cat.obj", &vertices1, &indices1);

    ab.StartLoop(nCmdShow, update);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```